# How to prove the fact that ANY motion of body is superposition of translational and rotational motion of and about centre of mass respectively?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

According to University Physics

Every possible motion of a rigid body can be represented as a combination of translational motion of cm and rotation about centre of mass. This is true even if centre of mass is accelerating

How can the above statement be proved. If a rigourous proof can be given thats good but only an intuitive explanation about this fact and how is it true for ANY motion and even if centre of mass is not having constant velocity would be sufficient ?

Comment: More generally, any motion is the combination of a rotation about **any** point (not only the centre of mass) and a translation of that point. This follows from [Euler's Rotation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem). There is nothing special about the centre of mass in this respect.

Comment: Okay how can we prove this in a simple way ?

Comment: Have you tried to read the links? Wikipedia provides a proof which involves no equations.